# how to use derby db data with Lazarus

Tags: derby, lazarus

I have a java program using a derby db in Eclipse.   I want to use this derby db data with a new program I am about to create with the Lazarus ide.   Can I connect direct to the derby db, if so how.  Or do I need to export the derby db in some way to use with the Lazarus ide, if so   how would I do this?

Answer (score 0):

if you decide with export variant, then .csv (comma separated value) is probably the best inter database. 
I have some experience with tdbf.
But from what I've read sqlite will be the best option.

I'm sorry for posting this as answer i have only 42 points reputation and can't post it as comment (need 50 for it)

Answer (score 0):

Does derby support ODBC? Lazarus has a ODBC connection that can be used to connect databases that are not directly supported.

I searched quickly, but mostly saw references to older commercial Derby ODBC drivers. And it will probably depend on OS.